# Why is this awk so much faster than in perl

Tags: perl

In AWK:

```
{
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if ($i in good) g++ ;
    if ($i in bad ) b++ ;
  }
}
```

in Perl:

```
while (<>) {
  foreach $word ( split ) { 
    if (exists($good{$word})) { $g++ } ;
    if (exists( $bad{$word})) { $b++ } ;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I thought for certain perl would be faster.

Loading the "good" and "bad" hashes is NOT the problem because the input is so much much bigger than the sentiment word lists.

Comment: If it's your belief that _'Loading the "good" and "bad" hashes is the problem'_, then maybe you should include the code that does that?

Comment: Perl is a general-purpose programming language with an emphasis on text processing, whereas awk is a much more domain specific tool for text processing. You'll always find a case where a single-purpose tool outperforms a general-purpose language. However, I'm not convinced that your two programs are actually equivalent – is `i` an integer or a string? (but that might just be my awk-noobishness speaking)

Comment: How big are the `good` and `bad` hashes? How big is the input?

Comment: @Miller Loading the hashes is NOT the problem (typo).  Sorry.

Comment: @KeithThompson the hashes are between 2,000 and 5,000 words.  They're very small compared to the hundreds of Megabytes of text.

Comment: how much faster is "much faster"?  awk is pretty fast, so I wouldn't be surprised if it were some faster.  do awk and perl come up with the exact same results?

Comment: Part of the reason is probably that split() in perl takes a regular expression as its splitter, not just a string.  Retry your benchmark with a more complicated separator, like "\b(and|or|nor)\b" and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection. The unnamed array created by split() is still being created on the heap for each line and eventually being deref'd and GC'd. Each element of that array is being copied to $word, and $word itself is deref'd at scope exit and eventually GC'd.

awk doesn't have any of that crap because it's not a general-purpose language. The awk script is indexing through the fields, and the underlying field array is allocated only once and reused through the lifetime of the program (since that's what awk does - split each line into words, always).

Comment: Thanks; this makes sense.  is there some way to make perl behave as awk?  global stack variables?